# What is the earliest form of Ashtpaad (8×8) board?

Tags: history, chessboards

An Ashtpaad board (8×8) is a smaller version of an Dashpaad board. This board was used extensively on which other variants were evolved in century.

What did an Ashtpaad board look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historians and chess board collectors have agreed that the Ashtpaad board was very popular some 1600 yrs ago. This board had total 16 crosses:

- 4 crosses at each corner called camps or palaces,
- 2 crosses on 4th and 5th square (on 1st row  and 8th row.), and
- 4 crosses on 1st 4th and 5th and 8th square (on 4th row and 5th row.)

[image: Ashtpaad board. Credit goes to Rick Knowlton]

The Ashtpaad board was primarily designed in sunhemp, cotton and silk threads. Gold or Silver threads marked the square-border, lines, and crosses (camps or palaces).

Later when Persian chess evolved, these palaces were removed.